# Why does mod_rewrite [F] forbidden return a 404 instead of 403?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have this simple `mod_rewrite` rule in my `.htaccess`, and both my browser tools (Firebug and Web Dev Toolbar) and my apache logs are showing the server returning a 404 instead of 403. Just wondering if this is normal, and if not, what can I do to remedy it?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(192\.168\.0\.11|192\.168\.0\.161)$
    RewriteRule ^(admin|login\.php) - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Server replies:

```
GET login.php 404 Not Found
```

Log file shows:

```
(404) (Request:) "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1"
```

**EDIT 1:**

One more thing. Should I include the [L] last flag after the [F] forbidden? e.g. `[F,L]` Thanks! :)

**EDIT 2:**

The files in question most definitely exist. When I change the IP address to allow myself access, I am able to http to them with no problem. Also, when I change the [F] to [G], the expected server response (410 Gone) is returned.

Comment: do you have any custom error pages?

Comment: I was just thinking about custom error pages. Each of my vhosts has this: `ErrorDocument 401 /404.php, ErrorDocument 403 /404.php, ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`. Each error points to 404.php, but does that have anything to do with the ACTUAL error returned by the server?

Comment: That is ABSOLUTELY the problem. The file 404.php does not exist. Lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, my apache2 vhost has the following `ErrorDocument` directives:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

... and the 404.php file does not exist (purposely). When 403 is commented out, `[F]` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly shouldn't do.

Are you sure that the condition and rule are matching? Does login.php really exist?

If you have no other `RewriteRule`'s then there's not much sense/difference in using an `[L]` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your rewrite rule is matching.  I would break it down and check your rewritecond and rewriterule seperately.

Comment: Yes, it is most definitely matching because when I change the IP address to allow myself to the files in question, I am allowed access.